# flow chart with both horizontal and vertical nodes

Tags: r, flowchart, diagrammer

I want to create a flow chart that contains both vertical and horizontal flowing nodes.

I have attempted to do this using library(DiagrammeR) with this code.

```
  `library(DiagrammeR)

   grViz(diagram = "digraph flowchart {
   node [fontname = helvetica, fontsize = 9, shape = rounded, penwidth = 1.0]
   graph[nodesep = 0.5]
   tab1 [label = '@@1']
   tab2 [label = '@@2']
   tab3 [label = '@@3']
   tab4 [label = '@@4']
   tab5 [label = '@@5']
   tab6 [label = '@@6']
   tab7 [label = '@@7']
   tab8 [label = '@@8']
   
   tab1 -> tab3;
   tab2 -> tab4;
   tab3 -> tab4;tab4 -> tab5;
   tab5 -> tab6;
   tab6 -> tab7;
   tab7 -> tab8;}

   [1]: 'KNOWN MAKE (N=500000)'
   [2]: 'MEN (N=400000)'
   [3]: 'UNKNOWN MAKE (N=12000)'
   [4]: 'CAR (N=488174)'
   [5]: 'PLANE (N=462050)'
   [6]: 'HORSE (N=442247)'
   [7]: 'BIKE (N=441912)'
  [8]: 'WALK (N=441343)'")
```

But, this only produces vertical flowing nodes- output included below.
[flow chart - not desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P13m.png)

I want the arrow that leads to ''WALK'' to flow from left to right (horizontal) of ''BIKE'' rather than down (vertical).

Any help will be appreciated. I have updated this to include a desired output.
[image]
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUWEU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: This was a lot of try and error, but now I think we got it:
(removed first answer):

```
library(DiagrammeR)


grViz(diagram = "digraph flowchart {
  node [fontname = helvetica, fontsize = 9, shape = rounded, penwidth = 1.0]
  graph[nodesep = 0.5, rankdir = TB]
  tab1 [label = '@@1']
  tab2 [label = '@@2']
  tab3 [label = '@@3']
  tab4 [label = '@@4']
  tab5 [label = '@@5']
  tab6 [label = '@@6']
  tab7 [label = '@@7']
  tab8 [label = '@@8' shape=rectangle color=black style='filled,bold' fillcolor=white];
  subgraph {
    rank = same;
    tab7;
    tab8 [color=black fillcolor=white style='filled,bold'];
  }
  
  tab1 -> tab3;
  tab2 -> tab4;
  tab3 -> tab4;
  tab4 -> tab5;
  tab5 -> tab6;
  tab6 -> tab7;
  tab7 -> tab8;
  
}
  
[1]: 'KNOWN MAKE (N=500000)'
[2]: 'MEN (N=400000)'
[3]: 'UNKNOWN MAKE (N=12000)'
[4]: 'CAR (N=488174)'
[5]: 'PLANE (N=462050)'
[6]: 'HORSE (N=442247)'
[7]: 'BIKE (N=441912)'
[8]: 'WALK (N=441343)'")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The idea however, is not to get every node to flow from left to right. Rather, i want everything to flow from top to bottom except the last node, which should flow from left to right.

Comment: I have updated the post to include a picture of the desired output

Comment: Excellent. Work perfectly well.                                                                            
 subgraph {  } did the job